# Empty route leeds to 404-Error - SilverStripe 3.5

Tags: php, silverstripe

Like superficial descriped in [SilverStripe Docs](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.2/developer_guides/controllers/routing/), I'm trying to set a custom controller for my homepage.

I changed the default homepage link to 'custom-home' and added those two routes.
The second one,  with the path in it works and directs me to my controller. The first (empty) one just sends me to an 404-error page.

Couldn't figure out how to fix that. Any suggestions?

routes.yml

```
Director:
  rules:
    '': 'MyHome_Controller'
    'custom-home': 'MyHome_Controller
```

_config.php

```
RootURLController::set_default_homepage_link('custom-home');
```

MyHome_Controller.php

```
<?php
class MyHome_Controller extends Page_Controller {

  private static $allowed_actions = [];

  private static $url_handlers = [];

  public function init() {
    parent::init();
  }

  public function Link($action = null) {
    return Director::baseURL() . 'custom-home';
  }

  public function index() {
    $data = [
      'Title' => 'Hello World',
      'ClassName' => __CLASS__,
    ];

    return $this
      ->customise($data)
      ->renderWith([__CLASS__, 'Page']);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the way the empty route (`RootURLController`) works is that you're telling it the `URLSegment` of a page in the CMS that should resolve to the root URL. So I think what you need to do is go into the CMS and change the URLSegment of your CustomHomePage to 'custom-home'.

Comment: The problem is, that's no page. just a Controller

Comment: Is this for a SPA? Are all your routes being handled client side?

Comment: SPA = Single Page Application? It's mainly meant as a test, for websites where I want to create an accessible page with just a controller. No database entries no possibility to manage that special page over the cms.